# Не выполняется прокрутка после изменения state

Tags: reactjs

После загрузки чата у меня должна срабатывать прокрутка в самый низ, но она не работает.
Срабатывает только, если я отложу прокрутку на 3ms. Подскажите, что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне кажется что это из-за того, что корневой компонент обновляется чуть дольше.

Comment: Если я понял правильно [это объяснение](https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/2f525c06-3623-4119-837a-ea565e6d1abd/y) , сначала срабатывает прокрутка а потом отрисовываются компонеенты?

Comment: ну и это плюс зависит от версии react

Comment: @Alexandr скорее всего так. React подготовил HTMLElement, но еще не вставил его в DOM документа.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что это особенность Virtual DOM. React подготовил HTMLElement, но еще не вставил его в DOM документа. Поэтому функция прокрутки не сработала ожидаемым образом.

На уровне React получилось это решить только путем асинхронного вызова через несколько миллисекунд.

Я нашел более привлекательное решение с помощью CSS. Я добавил на контейнер прокручиваемой области с помощью flex обратное размещение элементом. И содержимое контейнера дополнительно обернул в еще один div, чтобы дочерние элементы не "реверснулись".

HTML

```
<div class="dialog-container">
    <div class="dialog-sheet">
        <div class="dialog-message">1</div>
        <div class="dialog-message">2</div>
        <div class="dialog-message">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dialog-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

В таком случае, прокрутка у меня работает снизу-вверх. Как мне нужно и при этом элементы имеют четкий порядок.

Comment: Почему это нужно реализовывать колбеком в componentDidMount?

Comment: @Alexandr не нашел альтернативу

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, из-за особенностей React, сначала вы скроллите вниз, и только потом добавляете элемент в state.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```js
setImmediate(() => {
    this.scrollToBottom();
});
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_window_setimmediate